# How to use braces in angular

Tags: angular, angular5

I am not getting the required output as 20.

What is wrong with this ?

```
{{x = 4*5}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not use assignment operator, only use numbers or variables.

**these curly braces '{{ }}' are said to be an**

### interpolation

How it can be used?

In your html-template, write it as

```
X = {{ 4 * 4 }} // X = 16
X = {{ variable * 4 }}
X = {{ variable1 * variable2 }}
```

these variables are properties of your component class (controller class)

Comment: Thanks, now I got it right

Answer (score 1):

`Interpolation {{....}}` is the simplest view to bind data to the template.
**What  interpolation can do:**

1. expressions `{{2+2}}` Angular evaluates the expression and display the result in the browser `4`.
2. you can perform String concatenation `{{"welcome"+ name}}`.
3. you can use built-in javascript property and methods:
     `{{name.length}}` which will display `length` of the string.
     `{{name.toUpperCase()}}`
4. you can also call method defined in the component
    `{{greet()}}` which is defined as `greet(){return 'hello user';}`in your component

**What  interpolation cannot do:**
 1. you cannot assign the result of an expression to a variable within
    `{{x=2+2}}`  interpolation.

2. Access to the global javascript variable such as window ,screen
   is not allowed  `{{window.href.location}}`
3. `new` keyword is not allowed
4. chaining expressions with `;` or `,` increment and decrement operators
   (++ and --) are not allowed

Answer (score 0):

you can use below string interpolation

```
{{'x = '}} {{4*5}}
```